# Is MongoDB a right choice as persistent storage for application logs

Tags: mongodb, logging, persistent-storage

Is MongoDB a right choice as persistent storage for application logs?
Considering for an application which creates 15 GB log data per day.

Answer (score 1):

It's technically viable, particularly if you're emitting JSON-formatted log messages, but Elastic Search is much more tailored to storing and searching log data. There is an ecosystem of tools for storing and searching logs in [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/), including Kibana and Graylog, that make this even easier.